# Flyway using Testcontainers Optimization

Tags: java, spring, flyway, testcontainers

We have encountered a problem where we have many tests running inside a test container, and before each test, migration starts, resulting in a significant amount of time being consumed. Could you please share some ways to improve the test performance?

Comment: Provide some test samples and configs you are using

Comment: No sure way to make suggestions because I don't understand what exactly is slowing things down. Heck, what kind of database is it?

Comment: Is this a problem introduced in Flyway v10?